# wicked_pdf does not include styles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins, wicked-pdf

I used
 `<%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "pdf" %>` 
it shows the following output in the html

`<link href="/stylesheets/pdf.css?1302860585" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="file:///home/likewise-open/NEXTBRIDGE/nazar.hussain/osd/development/atlantis/public/stylesheets/pdf" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

But when create the pdf it do not have any style. If i copy all css from the file to the header of the page, it includes all styles. What is the issue and how to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally haven't had any trouble with this method, but I've seen others that have.

I just pushed some updates to the main project that should resolve this issue for you.

wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag now will inline any css files passed in directly into the markup.

I also updated the Github issue you created.

Comment: I also resolved the issue with inline technique. I used

`<%= render :file=>path_to_css_file %>` in the `head` tag of the page.

So it means your latest commit will also resolve the issue.